# Camera2api How to solve ? E/BufferQueueProducer: dequeueBuffer: attempting to exceed the max dequeued buffer count (4)

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am using Samsung-A10
with sdk 28

I am trying to take images using the camera2api but always after collecting 14 frames I get

```
I/com.oculid.daq: NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 3481(447KB) AllocSpace objects, 33(1580KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 3MB/7MB, paused 149us total 174.997ms
D/NetworkManagementSocketTagger: tagSocket(92) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
D/NetworkManagementSocketTagger: tagSocket(100) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
D/NetworkManagementSocketTagger: tagSocket(96) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
D/NetworkManagementSocketTagger: tagSocket(101) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
D/NetworkManagementSocketTagger: tagSocket(106) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
D/IR_CAMERA: camera stateCallback onError
E/BufferQueueProducer: [ImageReader-1280x720f100m1-965-0] dequeueBuffer: attempting to exceed the max dequeued buffer count (4)
```

I can see that behavior in certain phones models, I am trying to understand what this error means and how to solve it,
Will be happy for any leads.

I am attaching here my OnimageAvailable in case its help

```
    private ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
        @Override
        /*
         * gets a  the "reader" the callback is associated with.
         * transfer to bytes
         */

        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
            //Log.i(TAG,"readerListener on onImageAvailable");
            long imageReaderTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos();
            frameIndexForFileName++;
            //Log.i(TAG, String.format("Frame index: %08d", frameIndexForFileName));
            try (Image image = reader.acquireNextImage()) {

                //convert the image to bytes
                ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                buffer.get(bytes);

                double frameCaptureDuration = (double) (SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos() - imageReaderTime) / 1000000;
                Log.i(TAG, String.format("TIME_MEASUREMENT: Capture of frame %08d took %f ms", frameIndexForFileName, frameCaptureDuration));

                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, stream);
                byte[] compressImage = stream.toByteArray();
                bmp.recycle();
                //image.close();
                //reader.discardFreeBuffers();
                imageListener.onImage(compressImage, imageReaderTime);



            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!onImageAvailable: " + e );
            }
        }
    };
```

thanks

Comment: I can't see in the code where you close the image. You need to [close](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Image#close()) all images to make buffers available for next frames

Comment: i just add ```image.close()```  after the ```ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();``` did not change the bug

Answer (score 2):

I found a fix for the Buffer problem. Changing the ImageReader ImageFormat from JPEG to a raw format (YUV_420_888 usually also used for video) and converting the images later to RGB for the jpegs solved the issue for the Samsung A10, I’ve also tested it on a Samsung A5, and Huawei, the Fairphone and the Pocophone. It seems to work on all phonee.  I’ve read a lot about real time camera applications and it seems like using raw for the single frames is recommended due to performance advantages.

Comment: Hey how did you do the YUV_420_888 to RGB conversion?